# Base64 decode Stuck

Tags: java, android

i need to convert a base64 value into string array so simply i have write this :

```
String s[] = new String[partyname.length];
        for(int i=0;i<=partyname.length;i++)
        {
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(partyname[i], Base64.DEFAULT);
                String string = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
                s[i] = string;
                System.out.println("string is ::" + string+s[i]);


        }
```

but i dont know why it raise null pointer error at `s[i] = string;` line if i remove it then working fine so please help me out.

Comment: s is null (from the first line?)

Comment: Given that you have 2.8k rep, I think the solution here is to get more rest.

Comment: also you are terminating the loop at partyname.length - so dereferencing paryname[i] will fail on the last iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your String array that s references first. You have

```
String[] s = null;
```

So when you try to use s such as

```
s[i] = string;
```

Then there *s* is still null, and trying to get the *i* element of *s* gives you the null pointer.

From the rest of the code I think you want a String array with the same number of elements as party name, so you need

```
String[] s = new String[partyname.length];
```

Answer (score 6):

Because `s` is null.

You probably want this as the first line:

```
String[] s = new String[partyname.length];
```

Comment: @Dr.nik: You have removed what?

Answer (score 1):

As said, s is null, I want to add another consideration: 
The for loop should be: `for(int i=0;i<partyname.length;i++)` instead of `for(int i=0;i<=partyname.length;i++)`

Comment: Good catch. Missed that when answering the original question.

Comment: Thanks, it isn't THE problem to solve, but it will be the next.